# Array not being copied in Parse Cloud code

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I am facing problems while copying array in Parse Cloud Code. In findAllAssociatedBrands functions below, I am using Parse Queries to get an array on success callback. On success callback, the log statement: console.log(JSON.stringify(brandList[i])); prints the array element, and then I copy all the elements in a new array. After the for loop, the log statement displays the new array as [] and there are no elements in it. What is it that I missing?

```
function findAllAssociatedBrands(beaconObj) {

var typeOfBeacon = beaconObj.get("type");
var beaconBrandRelation = beaconObj.relation("brand");
var query = beaconBrandRelation.query();
var listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands = [];

query.find({
    success: function(brandList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < brandList.length; i++) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(brandList[i]));
            listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands[i] = brandList[i];
        }

        console.log(listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Beacon Brand Relation Error: " + error.code + "  " + error.message);
    }
});

return listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

query.find() is a async function so the last line in the findAllAssociatedBrands() function executes immediately after query.find() so query.find() usually won't even have enough time to run the success callback so you have to tie "return listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands;" to the end of the success callback.

```
function findAllAssociatedBrands(beaconObj) {

var typeOfBeacon = beaconObj.get("type");
var beaconBrandRelation = beaconObj.relation("brand");
var query = beaconBrandRelation.query();
var listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands = [];

query.find({
    success: function(brandList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < brandList.length; i++) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(brandList[i]));
            listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands[i] = brandList[i];
        }

        console.log(listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands);
return listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Beacon Brand Relation Error: " + error.code + "  " + error.message);
    }
});


 }
```

Comment: Yes, but success does run after sometime in that case it should populate the listOfAllBeaconsAssociatedBrands and display it. Right?

Comment: right, but at the millisecond that you "return listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands;" listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands is not populated and is just empty like how it was initialized at the beginning with "var listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands = [];"  By the time listOfAllBeaconAssociatedBrands is populated, it's too late because execution has already moved onto many hundreds of lines of code by that time.